# Can I improve the efficiency of this command pipeline using process substitution?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, io-redirection, tail

I would like to improve the efficiency of the following set of bash commands I have created. I would like to try to make this more efficient or at least spread the processing to more cores, possibly using Process Substitution.

```
wget file.zip -qO- | funzip | tail -n +2 | bzip2 -qc > newfile.bz2
```

File.zip is extremely large and I would like to avoid writing to disk until the last moment.

I am new to process substitution and have tried things like:

```
bzip2 -qc > newfile.bz2 <(tail -n +2) <(wget file.zip -qO- | funzip)
```

with little success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A pipe is not a single process; each command is a separate process, but you are constrained by the fact that each process depends on the output of the previous command for its input. You have an essentially serial workflow; there isn't really any opportunity for parallelization. The pipe already makes efficient use of CPUs; `funzip` and `bzip2` can work in parallel as long as, for example, `bunzip2` can read its input as fast as `funzip` can write to it. (The `tail` process is essentially just a pure IO bridge.)

Comment: To expand on @chepner, the pipe and the process substitution are just different ways of accomplishing the same task.  The number and type of file descriptors created might differ, but the number of processes (and the order in which they must run) is the same.

Comment: you could make the disk writes less frequent by buffering the output, only writing to newfile.bz2 in e.g. 10MB chunks: `wget file.zip -qO- | funzip | tail -n +2 | bzip2 -qc | dd of=newfile.bz2 bs=10M`.